# A list of UML diagram for c#

Tags: c#, uml

I will have an exam for c# soon. However I could not find any sufficent diagrams to study my exam.
For instance I don't know how to write

> +Mileage : double {property}

or

> +GetBillingType():BillingType {abstract}

is there any extended list of UML for C# that shows everything?

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409437.aspx) might be of use.